# INNER JOIN in EntityRepository

Tags: symfony

When to execute the following query I have this error message

```
The target-entity Tennis\Bundle\Entity\clubs cannot be found in 'Tennis\Bundle\Entity\UsersClubs#club'
```

the query:

```
SELECT club.id, club.name, user_club.points, user_club.played
FROM TennisBundle:UsersClubs user_club
  INNER JOIN TennisBundle:Clubs club ON club.id = user_club.club
WHERE user_club.user = :user
ORDER BY user_club.points DESC
```

**club**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="clubs")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tennis\Bundle\Entity\ClubsRepository")
*/
class Clubs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $name;

    ...

}
```

**user club**:

```
class UsersClubs
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tennis\Bundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", nullable=false)
    */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tennis\Bundle\Entity\clubs", inversedBy="club")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="club", nullable=false)
    */
    private $club;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
    */
    private $points = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
    */
    private $played = 0;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Load and clear i think? Or else what is your question?

Comment: Why this query not works ?

Comment: Because it needs Tennis\Bundle\Entity\clubs which cannot be found. Maybe it has to be club without the letter s? Just check the path where the entity is stored and the filename + class name

Comment: paste your ``UserClubs`` and ``Clubs`` entities definitions here

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0ta3PizB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok the was in my entity definition: Tennis\Bundle\Entity\Clubs instead of Tennis\Bundle\Entity\clubs